# Returned values not used

Tags: python-3.x

```
>>> def square(x):
        print('LINE A:', x)
        x = x*x
        print("LINE B:", x)
        return x


>>> if __name__ == '__main__':
        x = 5
        print("LINE C:", x)
        square(x)
        print("LINE D:", x)
        square(x + 1)
        print("LINE E:", x)
```

Produces:

```
LINE C: 5
LINE A: 5
LINE B: 25
25
LINE D: 5
LINE A: 6
LINE B: 36 
36
LINE E: 5
```

In my understanding, it should return the following:

```
LINE C: 5
LINE A: 5
LINE B: 25
25
LINE D: 25
LINE A: 25
LINE B: 676 
676
LINE E: 676
```

In the first(top) function, I assign the parameter x with x*x. Therefeore, in the if **name** == '**main**': function, print("LINE D:", x) is suppose to print the x that is returned by the square(x) that is called previously. But for some reason this is not the case, what did I do wrong? Or is it my understanding that is incorrect?

P.S. I am not exactly seeking to correct the function. I am simply finding an explanation to why it works this way.

Comment: You need to write `x = square(x)` instead.

Comment: I am not exactly seeking to correct the function. I am simply finding an explanation to why it works this way.

Comment: The `square()` function is not manipulating directly the `x` variable that resides in `main()`. Instead, it copies its value and assigns it to a local variable that is also called `x`. `x` (main) remains unchanged unless you assign it the return value of `square(x)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each function in python has its own scope. In this case, the `x` in `square` is different from the `x` in main. When you call `square(x)`, the `x` from main is copied to the `x` in square. The `x = x*x` statement in `square` only updates the local `x`.